# Override Primefaces 4.0 CSS

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I'm using facelets and I have the following layout page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title><ui:insert name="title" /></title>
    <link href="../css/cssmenu/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>                        

    <div id="layout">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td height="500" valign="top">
                    <div id="menu">
                        <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />

                    </div>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="content">
                        <ui:insert name="content">
                        </ui:insert>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Also my menu.xhtml page is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>

    <h:form id="menuForm">
        <div id="menuLateral">
            <p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />

            <p:panelMenu style="width:200px" id="panelMenu">
                <p:submenu label="Incidentes">
                    <p:menuitem value="#{menuController.test}"  action="#{menuController.save}"
                         ajax="true" update="messages" 
                        icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                </p:submenu>
                <p:submenu label="Non-Ajax Menuitem">
                    <p:menuitem value="Delete" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                </p:submenu>
                <p:separator />
                <p:submenu label="Navigations">
                    <p:submenu label="Links" icon="ui-icon-extlink">
                        <p:submenu label="PrimeFaces" icon="ui-icon-heart">
                            <p:menuitem value="Home" url="http://www.primefaces.org"
                                icon="ui-icon-home" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Docs"
                                url="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html"
                                icon="ui-icon-document" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Download"
                                url="http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html"
                                icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Support"
                                url="http://www.primefaces.org/support.html"
                                icon="ui-icon-wrench" />
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:menuitem value="Mobile" icon="ui-icon-signal" />
                </p:submenu>
            </p:panelMenu>
        </div>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

What I want is to make my primefaces menu to look like this one:
http://cssmenumaker.com/builder/1442641  (or anyone actually, its just an example)

However im not sure what my css stylesheet should contain or what to do to accomplish it. I will deeply appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Override Primefaces 4.0 CSS

```
Step 1 : You just override css file in primefaces 4.0

         <h:outputStylesheet href="../css/layout.css" />
```